# Range filter works only in first controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have range filter (code below) and it work only on my first controller.
I added in the others controllers this filter in the same way in app.js and in html and not working and I don't know why?

In console I don't have errors.

Range filter code:

```
appPokayoke.filter('rangeFilter', function() {
    return function(input, min, max) {
        min = parseInt(min); //Make string input int
        max = parseInt(max); //Make string input int

        for (var i=min; i<max; i++)
            input.push(i);
            return input;
    };
});
```

my app.js file:

```
(function(){


    var appPokayoke = angular.module('appPokayoke', ['ngRoute', 'pyService']);

    appPokayoke.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

        code ...

    }]);

    appPokayoke.controller('DrawingsListCtrl', ['$scope', 'drawings', 'pantons', function ($scope, drawings, pantons) {

        code ...

    }]);

    appPokayoke.controller('DrawingDetailsCtrl', ['$scope','drawings', 'articles', '$routeParams', 'articlesOfDrawings', 'pantonClass', function ($scope, drawings, articles, $routeParams, articlesOfDrawings, pantonClass, rangeFilter ) {

        code ...

    }]);

    appPokayoke.controller('CreateArticleCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','pantons','$routeParams', 'articles', '$location', function ($scope, $http, pantons, $routeParams, articles, $location, rangeFilter) {

        code ...

    }]);

    appPokayoke.controller('CreateArticleColorsCtr', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams', 'articles', '$location', 'articlesOfDrawings', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, articles, $location, articlesOfDrawings, rangeFilter ) {

        code ...

    }]);

    appPokayoke.filter('rangeFilter', function() {
        return function(input, min, max) {
            min = parseInt(min); //Make string input int
            max = parseInt(max); //Make string input int

            for (var i=min; i<max; i++)
                input.push(i);
                return input;
        };
    });

})();
```

in html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="7%">Lp.</th>
            <th  width="10%">Article <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </th>
            <th width="10%">Colors in article</th>
            <th ng-repeat="m in [] | rangeFilter:0:pyNumber track by $index">{{$index+1}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="article in articlesOfDrawings | filter : search track by $index">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in article" style="background-color: rgb({{column[1]}});"  ><p>{{ column[0] }}</p></td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT:** 
Code of controller where the filter not working:
        appPokayoke.controller('CreateArticleColorsCtr', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams', 'articles', '$location', 'articlesOfDrawings', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, articles, $location, articlesOfDrawings, rangeFilter ) {

```
        var drawingId = $routeParams.drawingId;
        var pyNumber = $routeParams.pyNumber;
        console.log(pyNumber);

        $scope.rangeFilter = function(max) {
          return max = pyNumber;
        };

       $scope.articleColors = {};
       $scope.articleColorsData = {};

       articles.getNewArticle(
            $routeParams.articleName, 
            $routeParams.drawingId,
            function (data) {
                if(data !== '') {
                    $scope.articleColors = data;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('not ok articleColors');  
                }
            }
        );

        articlesOfDrawings.getArticlesOfDrawings(
            $routeParams.pyNumber, 
            $routeParams.drawingId,
            function (data) {
                if(data !== '') {
                    $scope.articlesOfDrawings = data;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('not ok articlesOfDrawings');  
                }
            }
        );


        $scope.saveArticleColors = function (articleColorsData, success) {

            success = success || function() {};

            $http.post('api/admin/articles/save_colors/', 
                articleColorsData ).success(function (data){
                console.log(data);
                    success(data.articleColorsData);
                    $scope.articleColorsData = articleColorsData;
                    console.log($scope.articleColorsData);
                    //$location.path('/drawings/'+ drawingId + '/' + pyNumber);

            }).error(function (){
                console.log('Problem ArticleColors');
            });

        }

    }]);
```

Comment: could you add jsfiddle or plunker for your code, not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: I have working filter in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVzPyO).  In here it generate number of colum. Or you need all code?

Comment: I can see it works here , could you just upload the part that is not working ? or you can upload the full code and point the line number that contains the non-working part

Comment: I edited and added code of controller where the filter not working and the html when i use this filter Is already added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put pyNumber in your scope so that you can call it from your filter like this:

```
$scope.pyNumber = $routeParams.pyNumber;
        console.log($scope.pyNumber);

      // you don't need this function 
      //  $scope.rangeFilter = function(max) {
      //    return max = pyNumber;
      //  };
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Thats helps!! :)